# Enable Hidden Feature for Newsfeed Why?

Tags: feature, feature-activation, newsfeed, social-feed

I have seen Blogs where you can activate the "Hidden" News Feed Web Part though PowerShell and then add it to a Standard SharePoint Team Site.

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "6928b0e5-5707-46a1-ae16-d6e52522d52b" -Url "http://sp2013"
```

Why would someone want to do this and what is the benefit? I always click on "Follow" in the Team Site which shows up in my MySite.  If it is a Hidden feature it must be hidden for a reason.